# Haskell parallel map with `par` and `pseq`

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

I am doing some experiments with parallelism in Haskell. Part of it is inspecting differences between Strategies and ordinary `par` and `pseq` combinators.

I created a function like this :

```
parMap :: NFData b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parMap _ [] = []
parMap f (a:as) =
  let v = f a
      vs = parMap f as
  in rnf v `par` vs `pseq` v : vs
```

I am trying to achieve parallelism with as little libraries as possible (therefore no Strategies, no Par) and small level of abstraction as for Haskell.

With this function I am trying to perform matrix-matrix multiplication with one of those two functions:

```
matmultListPar :: (Num a, NFData a) => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
matmultListPar a b = parMap multiplyRowByEachColumn a
  where multiplyRowByEachColumn r = map (\c -> sum . zipWith (*) r $ c) $ b'
        b' = transpose b

matmultListParChunks :: (Num a, NFData a) => Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
matmultListParChunks size a b
  = let
        chunks = toChunks size a
        b' = transpose b
    in concat $ parMap (flip matmultList $ b) chunks
```

`matmultList` is defined as follows:

```
matmultList :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
matmultList a b = fmap multiplyRowByEachColumn a
  where multiplyRowByEachColumn r = fmap (\c -> sum $ zipWith (*) r c) $ b'
        b' = transpose b
```

And `toChunks` :

```
toChunks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
toChunks _ [] = []
toChunks size list
  = let (i, f) = splitAt size list
    in i : (toChunks size f)
```

Just for clarity - matrix is stored row-major.

My problem and hence questions are:

1. While applying Strategy `parList rdeepseq` to sheer `matmultList` I get almost two times speedup on two cores. With my `parMap` I get little to none speedup.
2. Inspecting spark statistics with `-s` switch for RTS I can see that most of sparks are GC'd for `parMap` (while converted for Strategy).
3. As you can guess no parallel speedup is achieved by my `parMap` (measured with `criterion` benchmarks) while it is by Strategy

I noticed while inspecting Haskell libraries code that `par` combinator uses function `par#` for sprking while Strategies use something like `spark#` (I am not able to find it anymore so I might be wrong).

I need `rnf` in `parMap` as `a` might be `[Double]` so sparking to WHNF is not enough (I did experiment with `force` in various places as well).

**Is the lack of speedup caused by my wrong implementation, too fine-grained computations (GC'd sparks) or differences between `par` and Strategies? Or something else entirely? How to achieve speedup with `par` and `pseq`?**

Comment: "I am trying to achieve parallelism with as little libraries as possible (therefore no Strategies, no Par) and small level of abstraction as for Haskell." I don't think this is a terrifically useful goal, but if you're sticking to it, I suggest you copy the definition of `Eval` and the code for `parEval` out of `Control.Parallel.Strategies` (you'll have to copy `rpar` too) and build your abstractions on that; it's a better-behaved parallelism primitive than `par`.

Comment: @dfeuer I am well aware of that it would be better idea to use Stategies, well ... however. By the way when you mention it - do you know some references to places where I can learn more about differences in internal implementation of Stategies and `par` primitives ?